# How to write OSLC query where clause in Maximo Anywhere to evaluate somevalue < now()

Tags: maximo-anywhere, oslc

I'm configuring Work Execution.  The Work Order History query that is called when retrieving past work orders for assets or locations is open-ended.  Consequently, several thousand rows are retrieved each time and the application times out. I can attach where clause (see below) to limit it to records with actfinish after a specific date.  However, what I want to do is something like this...

```
spi_wm:actfinish>now()-30


<!--WorkOrder History Asset Resource-->
    <resource id="workOrderHistoryAssetLoc" class="application.business.WorkOrderObject" defaultOrderBy="wonum asc" describedBy="http://jazz.net/ns/ism/work/smarter_physical_infrastructure#WorkOrder" name="workOrderHistoryAssetLoc" pageSize="50" providedBy="/oslc/sp/WorkManagement">
        <attributes id="workOrderHistoryAsset_attributes1">
            <attribute describedByProperty="dcterms:identifier" id="workOrderHistoryAsset_identifier_dctermsidentifier1" index="true" name="identifier"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="oslc:shortTitle" id="workOrderHistoryAsset_wonum_oslcshortTitle1" index="true" name="wonum"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="dcterms:title" id="workOrderHistoryAsset_description_dctermstitle1" index="true" method="descriptionChanged" name="description"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:status" id="workOrderHistoryAsset_status_spistatus" index="true" method="statusChanged" name="status"/>
            <localAttribute dataType="string" id="workOrderHistoryAsset_statusdesc_string" name="statusdesc"/>              
        </attributes>
        <queryBases id="workOrderHistoryAsset_queryBasesh">
            <queryBase defaultForSearch="true" id="workOrderHistoryAsset_queryBase_searchAllWorkOrdersh" name="searchAllWorkOrdersAsset" queryUri="/oslc/os/oslcwodetail?savedQuery=getWithComplexQuery"/>
            <!-- TODO AWH 20170130 - add where clause to this query  -->                                
        </queryBases>
        <whereClause clause="spi:status in ['COMP','CLOSE'] and spi_wm:actfinish>'2016-10-10T09:50:00-04:00'" id="workOrderHistoryAssetLoc_whereClause"/>
    </resource>
```

I see elsewhere where there are formulas in the app.xml but I don't know what types of operators or language is available to accomplish something like this.  I was hoping the whereClause attribute had the ability to use a resolverClass and resolverFunction so that I could replace a named parameter with a value derived from a javascript function... no dice. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What version of Maximo Anywhere are you using?

Comment: Scott, we're using 7.6.1 on MobileFirst 7.1

Comment: Have you tried changing the querybase and set that where clause in Maximo?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to set the where clause in the app.xml. While I think this *could* work, it would probably be a million times easier to do the following.

1. duplicate the resource, then comment out the original
2. Create a saved query in Maximo with the where clause you need 
    a. spi:status in ['COMP','CLOSE'] and spi_wm:actfinish>'2016-10-10T09:50:00-04:00'
3. Name the saved query "ANYWHERE_WOHIST" or something like that.
4. Modify the duplicate resource to point to your new saved query.

   ```
   <queryBase defaultForSearch="true" id="workOrderHistoryAsset_queryBase_searchAllWorkOrdersh" name="searchAllWorkOrdersAsset" queryUri="/oslc/os/oslcwodetail?savedQuery=ANYWHERE_WOHIST"/>
   ```

Also, this allows the query where clause to be managed in the backend, so when your users decide they want to see something else here you can mange the query within Maximo. We're nearing the end of our project with Anywhere, so feel free to reach out if you'd like to swap war stories.